# Google Maps Marker Tooltips not showing (API v3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm implementing a rather standard map with markers and tootips using Google Maps API v3.

I'm trying to go step by step, and I'm stuck when it come to have my markers clickable.
I read in the documentation that markers are clickable by default and will display whatever the `title` parameter is set to.

I'm successfully showing my markers in my map, at the expected location. But I can't show the tooltip. The marker looks as clickable (cursor changes), but nothing happens when clicking on them. I should expect the tooltip to show up.

Here is my code, which is a simple implementation of what I found in the API doc, with some twists.

**Notes : ** I'm iterating through a `stores` JS object to get all my data. the `name` property is plain text.

```
/*  Show Stores Data on Map
-----------------------------------------------------  */

var center = new google.maps.LatLng( 47.56980820673984, -71.09390248632815 );

function initialize()
{
  var mapOptions = {
  center   : center,
  zoom     : 6,
  mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  zoomControl : true,
  disableDefaultUI : true
};

theMap = new google.maps.Map(
  document.getElementById("storemap"), mapOptions );

/*  place markers on the map  */
$.each( stores, function(i,v)
{
  stores[i]['marker'] = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
      position : new google.maps.LatLng( this.coords.lat, this.coords.lng ),
      map      : theMap,
      title    : this.name
    });
});

}

initialize();
```

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Are you looking for an [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows) (appears when you click the marker) or a [tooltip](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) (title property, AKA "Rollover Text", appears when you mouseover the marker)?

Comment: Yeah you're spot on !

Comment: for me, if I have a map with many markers, the first marker that I hover over will pop-up the tooltip; but then when I move my mouse over other tooltips, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You might be misusing Jquery's .each, try this:

```
/*  place markers on the map  */
stores.forEach(function( store ){
  var tmpmarker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
      position : new google.maps.LatLng( store.coords.lat, store.coords.lng ),
      map      : theMap,
      title    : store.name
    }
  );
  google.maps.event.addListener(tmpmarker, 'click',
    (function(a){ 
      return function(){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 2));
      };  
    })(store)
  );
  store['marker'] = tmpmarker;
});
```

And as far as I know, there is no default popup when you click on a marker. The title attribute should show up as a tooltip on mouseover.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my use of $.each, as all my markers are properly created. Actually I confused tooltip and InfoWindows. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you guys I realized I totally misunderstood the documentation.

I confused `tooltip` with `InfoWindow` indeed. I needed an InfoWindow for my project, and tooltips are simple text appearing on a Marker's hover, while InfoWindows need their own constructor.

Thanks for the help.